# Totals columns google analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

Since GAPI has been deprecated I'm moving all my php code to the Google Analytics API with Service Account. Now im trying to change the code to do the same I did with GAPI.

One problem I found is that in GA-API you can't or at least I dont know how to do to get the totals of columns after running a request.
For instance, in GAPI I could do

```
$ga->requestReportData(blahblah dimensions = days)
```

and then To get the totals of columns I could do this:

```
$ga->getUniquePageViews()
$ga->getVisitors()
```

Now in GA-API we have `getTotalsForAllResults()`, which returns the totals for all results, but I can't think of a way to return the total of only one metric without having to iterate the entire object.

Answer (score 0):

Well wasn't that hard,

its is used as:

```
$ga->getTotalsForAllResults()['ga:visitors']
```